# Emoji unicode issue with java .jar

Tags: java, unicode, jar, emoji

I am developing chat application in J2SE which can also send emoticons to other user.

Application uses https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java  (  Vdurmont Emoji-java-2.1 jar),

I followed all thing whichever described on that link, All is running fine during development environment but when I make jar for same, **when I am sending emoticons to other user on web then it showing code (ðŸ˜¡ and ? ).**

Firstly I think its an issue of loading files from folder so used ClassLoader, 
 to get proper image but during creating jar it showing ?(question mark) , So I removed that code for understood you better.

Code is written below below:

```
public ChatUI() {

        initComponents();

        this.setLayout(new WrapLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        for (int i = 0; i < imageHexaCode.length; i++)
        {

            final javax.swing.JLabel imogis = new javax.swing.JLabel("&#x" + imageHexaCode[i] + ";");


            imogis.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

            imogis.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emoji_" + imageHexaCode[i] + ".png")));

            imogis.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

            imogis.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

            imogis.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 1));

            imogis.setForeground(Color.white);

            final int aa = i;

            imogis.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    JLabel jl = new JLabel("&#x" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ";");

                    jl.setName("&#x" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ";");

                    jl.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 1));

                    jl.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

                    jl.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

                    jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emoji_" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ".png")));

                    jl.setForeground(Color.white);

                    ChatPaneWrite.jtp.insertComponent(jl);

                    System.out.println("" + imogis.getText());

                    // you can open a new frame here as
                    // i have assumed you have declared "frame" as instance variable

                }

            });

            this.add(imogis);

        }

        this.revalidate();

        this.repaint();

    }
```

**Where imageHexaCode is array of string of imoticons.**

```
    static String[] imageHexaCode = {
            "1f621",
            "1f608",
            "2764",
            "1f494"
};
```

**&  jtp is JTextPane where inserting imoticons component when user click on label**

```
ChatPaneWrite.jtp.insertComponent(jl);
```

**Emoticons are stored in same package where I am writing that's why I did not use ClassLoader in line**

```
jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emoji_" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ".png")));
```

**or it can also write like for package ChatUI**

```
jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().ClassLoader.getResource("ChatUI/emoji_" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ".png")));
```

here is snap shots:

In jar at receive end showing that emoticons like this

[image]

**Please help me to sort it out.**

**Very thankful to all in advance**

Comment: Are you exporting the images in the JAR as well?

Comment: @abdulrahmank
 Yes, images are exporting  properly and showing at user interface, only sending and receiving have some issue .

Comment: haven't go into your code but from what displayed on UI, it looks garbage to me and may be caused by incorrect char encoding .  (For example, sender is sending UTF-16 characters and you are interpreting them as extended ASCII).  If it is the case it can also explain why you failed to lookup the emoji

Comment: @AdrianShum: If I am doing as you said, then why emoticons are working properly in development environment ?

Comment: may,Its working fine with NetBeans IDE current runtime project But After @DheerajUpadhyay build/making a .jar file with all necessary lib, Emoji unicode parse problem occurs

Comment: I have the same issue, it is not the because image file is missing in jar.
Its something related to parsing to unicode, when running as jar file.
Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

[emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) uses UTF-8 encoding for parsing and by default Netbeans also uses the same, that's why your parsing went fine when run in Netbeans.

But when you run the program as jar file, the encoding scheme will be based on your system environment.

As a quick solution, you can force use UTF-8 encoding to run your jar file.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your-jar-file.jar
```

Or if you want a programmatic solution, may use this code

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
java.lang.reflect.Field charset = null;
charset = java.nio.charset.Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
charset.setAccessible(true);
charset.set(null, null);
```

It is a general [issue](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java/issues/33) in the emoji-java by vdurmont. Both the solution works for me.

Comment: Hello, Krish 
I think this might be work but I solved this issue 4 year ago using
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
Thanks for your asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to check that the image resources are actually there at runtime. For example, add some logging of the value of `getClass().getResource("emoji_" + imageHexaCode[aa] + ".png")` to make sure it is not `null`. It is possible that in your development environment these are available but due to the way you are building your production version they are somehow getting missed or put in the wrong directory.

However, if you don't mind, I would also like to suggest an alternative approach: rather than using labels and image icons, have you considered building your emoticons into a font and then shipping the font file with your application? This would have several significant advantages:

1. You wouldn't need any special handling for the emoticons: just put the unicode text into a component that is using your custom font and the emoticons as well as all the other text will just work.
2. The font images can be vector images which means that they can scale nicely as the users change font size/zoom level etc.
3. The user can cut/copy/paste text containing the emoticons; since it is text it will again 'just work'.

If you decide to take this route, there is an excellent open-source font editor that I have used before called FontForge: https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/ . It's pretty easy: you just design the image in the appropriate slot for the character code and then export the font file.

Comment: Sir, I also did which you suggest but still problem not solved.

Comment: Sir, I extract jar file to see where production is storing images, first I know it may coz issue that's y I placed those emoji's in same folder where my class file is located, secondly, I  also did which you suggest but still problem not solved.